# Not understanding why I have to use json_decode twice. Laravel Migrations and Model

Tags: php, laravel

So consider the following migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdventureLogs extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('adventure_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('character_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('character_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('characters');
            $table->bigInteger('adventure_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('in_progress')->nullable()->default(false);
            $table->boolean('complete')->nullable()->default(false);
            $table->integer('last_completed_level')->nullable();
            $table->json('logs')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('adventure_logs');
    }
}
```

Notice the json column I create. `$table->json('logs')->nullable();`

From here, lets create a model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdventureLog extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'character_id',
        'adventure_id',
        'complete',
        'in_progress',
        'last_completed_level',
        'logs',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'complete'             => 'boolean',
        'in_progress'          => 'boolean',
        'last_completed_level' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function getLogsAttribute($value) {
        return json_decode(json_decode($value));
    }

    public function setLogsAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['logs'] = json_encode($value);
    }

    public function character() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Character::class);
    }

    public function adventure() {
        return $this->hasOne(Adventure::class, 'id', 'adventure_id');
    }
}
```

Notice this method:

```
public function getLogsAttribute($value) {
    return json_decode(json_decode($value));
}
```

this is wrong. Obviously.

So the json that is stored is:

```
[{"adventure":"sample"}]
```

So when I call: `$character->adventureLogs()->first()->logs` I get: `[{"adventure":"sample"}]`.

But if we change the function to what it's suppose to be:

```
public function getLogsAttribute($value) {
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

then I get: `"[{"adventure":"sample"}]"`.

I store data by doing:

```
AdventureLog::create([
   // .... Other attributes
   'logs' => ['adventure' => 'sample']
]);
```

So what am I doing wrong where I have to wrap the first `json_decode` into another one? I should not have to do that.

Comment: Can you do a simple `var_dump($value)` in that function so we can see whats actually in that field

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is what the dump shows: `""[{\"adventure\":\"sample\"}]""`

Comment: So where does `getLogsAttribute($value)` get called? And where do you get `$value` from before you pass it to that function

Comment: @RiggsFolly Read the docs attributes on models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> ... if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model

So just add

```
protected $casts = [
    ...
    'logs' => 'array',
];
```